Find last hash of a file relative to an arbitrary commit
I want the hash of the last commit for a specific file closest to an arbitrary commit without needing to do a checkout.
For example, suppose I want the latest hash of doc.md closest to 93b19868e6.  The result should be 2826596092.
             24bfbe13a8 * main.c: Add base36.
             7988ca6a48 * main.c: Fix build.
             50a72a08af * main.c: Update to 6.6.3.
             91ad8a1444 * build.mk: Use IMPORT_PATH2.
             2ce05b362c * doc.md: Move "Section 2.4" after "Section 5.1".
given this ->93b19868e6 * main.c: Add base32.
want this  ->2826596092 * doc.md: Fix menus.
             726e7e3996 * main.c: Enable tests.
             7878cd0659 * main.c: Fix build.
             227e0469db * doc.md: Simplify installation instructions
             93ccf08b4a * main.c: Deprecate use of curl.

It's possible to first checkout commit 93b19868e6 and then get the top log entry for doc.md:

git checkout 93b19868e6
git log -n 1 -- doc.md

However, I would like to do this in a script without modifying the current state of the directory.

git log accepts a commit as argument which will be used as the starting point (if omitted this is HEAD).
So if you do git log 93b19868e6 you will find all commits that are reachable from (= are ancestors of) 93b19868e6, and if you combine it with -n 1 and -- doc.md it should return what you want.

Interesting.  I had tried that, but with the --all flag.  Running git log -n 1 --all 93b19868e6 -- doc.md returns 2ce05b362c, which is the latest relative to HEAD.  However, running without --all returns 2826596092 as desired.

--all defeats specifying a commit to limit the result: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---all. It does the opposite, in a sense.
